# Embedded Field: must be instance of Model: <class 'django.db.models.base.Model'>

Tags: django, djongo

I tried to do a dummy seeder for the Entry model (extended from djongo model) with the object manager but I got an error while saving.

**Error:  must be instance of Model: <class 'django.db.models.base.Model'>`**

Python script

`<The complete python script used to produce the issue.>`

```py
from djongo import models
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Entry(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog
    )

    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = models.DjongoManager()


def build_dummy_entry():
    e = Entry.objects.create(
    headline='h1',
    blog={
        'name': 'b1',
        'tagline': 't1'
    })

    g = Entry.objects.get(headline='h1')
    assert e == g

    e = Entry()
    e.blog = {
        'name': 'b2',
        'tagline': 't2'
    }
    e.headline = 'h2'
    e.save()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help='Create a preset dummy entry'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            build_dummy_entry()
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'Successfully created dummy blog'))
        except Exception as e:
            raise CommandError(f'{e}')
```

Traceback

```
CommandError: Value: {'name': 'b1', 'tagline': 't1'} must be instance of Model: <class 'django.db.models.base.Model'>
```

## ---EDIT SOLUTION---

I was using the **1.3.1**.
I check the version **1.3.2 and 1.3.3** and it looks like these version **contains the fix for the instantiation error.**

Comment: could you show your manager? I think there is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error says, you should use model instance, but you're using dict.

```
def build_dummy_entry():
    e = Entry.objects.create(
        headline='h1',
        blog=Blog(**{'name': 'b2', 'tagline': 't2'}),
    )

    ...
```

Comment: Hi, as my Blog model is abstract I can't use the objects manager. But in the end your answer is correct, I just have to use the constructor of the Blog model with the spread operator. -> `e.blog = Blog(**dict_payload)`. Thanks a lots for you help 

Comment: I submitted you an edit with the right code. When you approved it I can valid your answer !

Comment: @JohnnyDaCosta I see. I didn't noticed that your model is abstract, reading your code again I saw that.  Glad it works, I'm happy to help. (The edit was accepted).